# Convert JSON string to JSON object so I don't need to change in the base jquery.dataTables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I'm using ASP.net MVC on the server side. Basically I have a model class, I normally `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataTableModel)` and send it back to `datatables.js`. After the conversion the json data looks like the following;

```
"{
"draw":1,
"recordsTotal":2,
"recordsFiltered":2,
"data":[
             {"PONumber":"PO 1234","SupplierNumber":"SUP 123","SupplierName":"Supplier 1","ProductDescription":"SUND Salt & Pep Grinder 6/210g","POQuantity":"6","POUOM":"12","BatchQuantity":"18","BatchUOM":"24","ShelfDate":"2016/02/24","ExpireDate":"2016/03/15","CreatedDate":"2016/02/23","CreatedBy":"HORIZON.COM\\mohammadi","POReceiveDate":"2016/02/20","Notes":"Note 1"},
             {"PONumber":"PO 1236","SupplierNumber":"SUP 124","SupplierName":"Supplier 2","ProductDescription":"365 Cinnamon Strick Whol 6/36g*","POQuantity":"6","POUOM":"12","BatchQuantity":"18","BatchUOM":"24","ShelfDate":"2016/02/25","ExpireDate":"2016/03/31","CreatedDate":"2016/02/23","CreatedBy":"HORIZON.COM\\mohammadi","POReceiveDate":"2016/02/25","Notes":"Note 2"}
        ]
}"
```

It gets the data alright. But if I don't convert it to in **jquery.dataTables.js** >> `_fnBuildAjax.baseAjax` >> `success` into the following `(between line 9 - 15)` it doesn't show data; gets an error can't find lenght of `undefined`, which I get.

```
    var baseAjax = {
        "data": data,
        "success": function (json) {
            var error = json.error || json.sError;
            if ( error ) {
                _fnLog( oSettings, 0, error );
            }

            var x = JSON.parse(json);
            oSettings.json = x;
            callback(x);

            //oSettings.json = json;
            //callback( json );
        },
        "dataType": "json",
        "cache": false,
        "type": oSettings.sServerMethod,
        "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
            var ret = _fnCallbackFire( oSettings, null, 'xhr', [oSettings, null, oSettings.jqXHR] );

            if ( $.inArray( true, ret ) === -1 ) {
                if ( error == "parsererror" ) {
                    _fnLog( oSettings, 0, 'Invalid JSON response', 1 );
                }
                else if ( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {
                    _fnLog( oSettings, 0, 'Ajax error', 7 );
                }
            }

            _fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );
        }
    };
```

Following are my js code binding with datatables.

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/Home/GetDateLogData",
        "type": "POST"            
    },

    "columns": [
        { "data": "PONumber" },
        { "data": "SupplierNumber" },
        { "data": "SupplierName" },
        { "data": "ProductDescription" },
        { "data": "POQuantity" },
        { "data": "POUOM" },
        { "data": "BatchQuantity" },
        { "data": "BatchUOM" },
        { "data": "ShelfDate" },
        { "data": "ExpireDate" },
        { "data": "CreatedDate" },
        { "data": "CreatedBy" },
        { "data": "POReceiveDate" },
        { "data": "Notes" }           
    ]
});
```

In the `ajax` part I've tried with `dataSrc` as well, didn't work.

```
"dataSrc": function ( json ) {
  var x = JSON.parse(json);
  return x;
},
```

**My question, is there any builtin extender to do that, or perhaps how can I make a prototype like thing for this?** I thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the `typeof` result, which you get after `JSON.parse`?

Comment: after JSON.parse its an object, before its a string.

Comment: Isn't this what you want? Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Yes thats correct, I want the object (I've put the JSON.parse in the baseAjax, original code is commented bellow) but I don't want to modify the datatables.js file. I wanted to know is there any builtin extender to do that, or perhaps how can i make a prototype like thing for this.

Comment: @Stryner I didn't write **jquery.dataTables.js**. I modified only where I needed. Yes, to your question, I'm getting a string.

Comment: Oh I see, that's an excerpt from DataTables. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just as a note: There is no such thing as a `JSON object`.  Once it has been parsed, its just a regular JavaScript object/primitive.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher you know what I mean :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of [**`dataSrc`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc#Types). It is not working because you are expected to return an **array** of items, i.e `data` :

```js
dataSrc: function ( json ) {
  json = JSON.parse(json);
  return json.data; 
},
```

PS: Why `"type": "POST"`?

Comment: Not for any reason.. to be honest.. :(